# How do I split a row into multiple columns in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table like below with columns A (string) and B ROW(int):

```
A   B
a   [1,2,3]
b   [0,0,5]
c   [3,1,4]
```

And I would like to split the second column (which contains a ROW type) into multiple columns this way:

```
A   B1 B2 B3
a   1  2  3
b   0  0  5
c   3  1  4
```

I believe this can be done with a SQL statement, but unnest will create new *rows* (which I don't want) and `split_part` does not work with the `ROW` type. How can I achieve this?

Comment: TBH it looks more like array, not row to me.

Comment: There are array types and row types in presto, this question is for ROW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming column `B` is a `ROW` type, you can use the `.*` `ROW` operator in [SELECT statements](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#select-expressions).

This syntax exists in Trino ([formerly PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) but not PrestoDB, so it depends on which version you're using for this to work. I'd recommend moving to Trino anyways if you haven't already.

Copy/Paste:

```
WITH t(a, b) AS (
  VALUES
    ('a', ROW(1,2,3)),
    ('b', ROW(0,0,5)),
    ('c', ROW(3,1,4))
  )
SELECT 
  a as A,
  t.b.* AS (B1, B2, B3)
FROM t;
```

Execution:

```
trino> WITH t(a, b) AS (
    ->   VALUES
    ->     ('a', ROW(1,2,3)),
    ->     ('b', ROW(0,0,5)),
    ->     ('c', ROW(3,1,4))
    ->   )
    -> SELECT
    ->   a as A,
    ->   t.b.* AS (B1, B2, B3)
    -> FROM t;
 A | B1 | B2 | B3
---+----+----+----
 a |  1 |  2 |  3
 b |  0 |  0 |  5
 c |  3 |  1 |  4
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an equivalent answer to the chosen solution, with a slightly different syntax:

```
SELECT
A,
B[1] AS B1,
B[2] AS B2,
B[3] AS B3
FROM table;
```